# Redirect to a https url on server rather than sending 3XX in express

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, https

I have a sample http server .
I have a post API which in some scenario have to route to a third party https-server.
Third party server also exposes a post API.

I dont want to send a redirect to client and do this silently on http server.

My application is built using express.
I have tried using request module and tried to use pipe like this .. but request is timing out.

```
    let request = require('request');
    console.log(`vishal going here for 300 `);
    var pipe = req.pipe(request.post('https url here'));
    var response = [];

    pipe.on('data', function (chunk) {
        response.push(chunk);
    });

    pipe.on('end', function () {
        var res2 = Buffer.concat(response);
        console.log(res2);
        res.send(res2);

    });
```

Not sure whats missing.
Also how to pass the body and hears to https server request

Comment: All traffic should absolutely be redirected with a 301 for HTTP to HTTPS. That's what all sites should do before using HTTPS. What's your goal in trying to do this without a 301 redirect?

Comment: well i am writing a mock backend server for my deployment use case.. in mock server i have certain end point for setting the error and in that case i expect to return error. But in cae there is no error it should hit the actual server and get the respone.. My UI client should not be shown any redirection

Comment: You can detect if a client is using HTTP or HTTPS. If HTTP, you can return an error. Force client to use HTTPS with error message and you won’t have to do any redirects.

Comment: well the actual server which i am saying is a https server